# Determine why a rego test fails

Tags: opa, rego

new to Opa/rego. So, I have some rego test code

```
test_protected_allow {
    test_token := test.create_test_token({
            "audience": "https://whatever.companyname.com",
            "network": "internal",
            "acl": ["WHATEVER_READWRITE_POLICY_RULE"],
    })
    test_request := test.create_test_request({
        "path": "/s3",
        "method": "POST",
        "token": test_token
    })
    allow_protected == true with input as test_request 
}
```

And it's outputting `"allow_protected": false`

Is there a way to troubleshoot *why* this test evaluates to false? Maybe some kind of verbose mode that says "Hey this was rejected because your audience was wrong" or something like that.

Hoping there is a generic answer to this question that will make posting my application code unnecessary (though I can if I'm wrong).

Comment: You can test it from the playground, by selecting the part of the code you want to evaluate and click the `Evalute Selection` button. If you are using VSCode, you could install the OPA extension and do the same, i.e., select the part of the code you want to evaluate and then use Command Palette to find the `Evaluate Selection` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it can be a bit hard to interpret at times, you can use the `--verbose`/`-v` flag to get a trace printed for your failing tests. If you have a policy like this:

```
package play

import future.keywords

allow {
     is_admin
}

is_admin {
     "admin" in input.user.roles
}

test_allow {
     allow with input as {"user": {"roles": ["developer"]}}
}
```

Running the test with the `-v` flag would provide an output like below:

```bash
❯ opa test --verbose .
FAILURES
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
data.play.test_allow: FAIL (288.292µs)

  query:1          Enter data.play.test_allow = _
  play.rego:13     | Enter data.play.test_allow
  play.rego:5      | | Enter data.play.allow
  play.rego:9      | | | Enter data.play.is_admin
  play.rego:10     | | | | Fail internal.member_2("admin", __local0__)
  play.rego:6      | | | Fail data.play.is_admin
  play.rego:14     | | Fail data.play.allow with input as {"user": {"roles": ["developer"]}}
  query:1          | Fail data.play.test_allow = _

SUMMARY
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
play.rego:
data.play.test_allow: FAIL (288.292µs)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FAIL: 1/1
```

The first "fail" here is introduced in:

```
play.rego:10     | | | | Fail internal.member_2("admin", __local0__)
```

Where `internal.member2` is the internal function name used for the `in` check, eventually leading to the rule evaluation failure:

```
play.rego:6      | | | Fail data.play.is_admin
```

While traces aren't super easy to read unless one is familiar with the internals of OPA evaluation, they can often help pointing one in the right direction.

For more quick-n-dirty debugging, liberal use of the [print](https://blog.openpolicyagent.org/introducing-the-opa-print-function-809da6a13aee) function is often the fastest way to figure out where things stopped working.

I wrote a little helper library to help work with [test assertions](https://github.com/anderseknert/rego-test-assertions) some time back, perhaps you'll find it helpful too.